# How are line numbers determined lldb?

Tags: c, lldb

I have a piece of C code that I'm trying to debug using lldb. I'm trying to set breakpoints on a certain line in the code,  but the line number in my code does not match where lldb lands.

I can see that it doesn't count empty lines, lines with commands, lines with variable declarations, lines that have `#include` statements etc., but I can't make lldb land on a certain line by trying to set breakpoints on different lines. Below is a sketch of the relevant parts the code. **Note** that I can't post the whole thing because it's too long, and also I did not write it, so I don't have the permissions to share it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
#include ...


// global var declarations
double X;
...
int ind;

int main()
{
     // variable declarations
     int a, b, c, i, j, N, Nc;
     ...
     double x, y, z;


     // some initializations and calculations
     a = 19;
     b = 10;
     c = a + b;

     // one for loop doing some calculations
     for (i=0; i<N; i++){
         // some calculations here
         a += c;
     }


     double En; // more var declarations

     myFunc(&(En));

     printf("hello world\n");

     // more declarations
     file = fopen("file1.dat","w");

     for(j=1; j<3; j++)
     {
         Nc = j;
     }

// rest of the code
}
```

I want to set a breakpoint at the line that contains `myFunc(&(En));`, which is line 130 in my original code. But when I set a breakpoint at 130 and run the program, it lands at `Nc = j;`. If I try setting breakpoints to 129, 128, 127, etc., I either end up at the same line, or the line right after the closing curly brace of the first for loop.

Why is this happening and how can I end up in the line containing `myFunc(&(En));`?

Comment: Did you compile with debug-info? Are you sure the debugger has the *correct* source file available?

Comment: @EOF Yes, I compile with the `-g` flag only.  I noticed that I did not recompile after adding a comment line. I recompiled and it worked now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps compiler optimisation? this for does exactly nothing and if the variable *Nc* is not used somewhere else can removed completely, or if it is - replaced by the *Nc = 3;*. To be honest I am not surprised. Set optimisation to *-Og*

Comment: I don't have optimization, as far as I know. I only have the the `-g` flag. `Nc` is used somewhere in the script, but I did not include it. I tried to use the flag `-Og`, but I get an error: `error: invalid integral value 'g' in '-Og'`.

Comment: what compiler do you use?

Comment: gcc. It turns out that the lines don't match because I did not re-compile after adding comments to the file, though.

Comment: :):):):) Good one :). Anyway if you want do disable all optimisations use -Og option. It has to work